# ClosedXML: how to check if worksheet exists?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML. I want to loop through all available sheets & delete them after a condition. but when I check if sheet exists, its throwing exception. below is my code. Please help me how to check validity of a sheet.

```
                for (int i = 1; i <= totalWorkSheets; i++)
                {
                    if (wb.Worksheet(i)!=null)
                    {
                        if (wb.Worksheet(i).Position != 1)
                        {
                            wb.Worksheet(i).Delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: basically it throws exception saying sheet i am checking doesn't exist. ex.Message = "There isn't a worksheet associated with that position."

Comment: You're modifying the collection as you iterate over it. Is that allowed? You might want to iterate in reverse order as you delete.

Comment: thanks BurnsBA. that helps. though solution you suggested is of generic collection, i was finding it difficult to apply for ClosedXML worksheet list. but it works fine here too!

Answer (score 0):

As @BurnsBA said iterate over it backwards so you don't modify the collection...

```
for (int i = totalWorkSheets -1 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (wb.Worksheet(i)!=null)
    {
        if (wb.Worksheet(i).Position != 1)
        {
            wb.Worksheet(i).Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bool tabExists = wb.Worksheets.Contains("TabName");